# Update user location after 15 minutes in background in android studio

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have to get the user location in every 15 minutes and upload it to server when app is minimized or phone is in sleep mode. It is working fine when app is in foreground but when app is in sleep mode nothing is working in higher devices.

```
//using alaram manager (MainActivity)
if (alarmManager != null) {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), 15 * 60000, 
notifyPendingIntent);
    }

//Alaram receiver broadcast
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    doBackgroundTask();
}
```

I have also implemented using work manager but it is also not working in higer devices

```
inside main activity
PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyLocationWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addTag(TAG)
            .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("Location", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, periodicWork);


inside worker class

public Result doWork() {

    callProfileService(new Listeners.IsSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(boolean success) {
            if (success)
            {
                displayNotification("My Location  Worker",type);
            }
        }
    });
    return Result.success();
}
```

Comment: https://ariefbayu.xyz/execute-periodic-process-under-15-minutes-cycle-using-workmanager-564c3ade94c4

Comment: You can use a WorkManager to do jobs in background periodically. did you try work manager?

Comment: yes, but not working with higher version when device is in sleep mode